# Inserting Excel formula that refers to alternative columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am trying to insert the following formula **='External Costs B0'!F73** in the same row of a sheet in consecutive columns, however with the cell reference "F73" in worksheet "External Costs" referring to alternate columns e.g F73, H73, J73, L73 etc.

Here is a screen shot of the spreadsheet with formula commented

[Screen Capture of formula sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SN1Ia.jpg)

This is the code I have tried but I am struggling to figure how to get the alternative column reference working.

```
Dim CostColumns As Long
```

'Select cell to start inserting the formula from

```
Range("E26").Select
```

'Start from column F (6) in the "External Costs B0" sheet and step to every alternate column

```
For CostColumns = 6 To 600 Step 2
    ActiveCell.Formula = "= ""'External Costs B0'!"" & Rows(73)Columns(CostColumns)"
```

Move to the next cell to insert the formula in and advance the column reference by 2 columns

```
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Next CostColumns
```

The net result is the same error I have seen in many posts:

Application-defined or object-defined error.

Here are many other syntax's for the formula insert I have tried with no success. Any help is greatly appreciated. The below refers to row 40 instead of row 73 in the External Costs B0 sheet as per the example above.

```
Range("E26").Select
 For CostColumns = 6 To 66 Step 2
    'ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "= worksheets("""External Costs B0""").Cells(40,6).Value"
    'ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='External Costs B0'!R[14]C[CostColumns]"
    'Range("E26:AK26").FormulaR1C1 = "='External Costs B0'!R[14]C[CostColumns]"
    'ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "= worksheets('External Costs B0')!" & " Rows(40)Columns(CostColumns)"
    'Range("E26:AK26").FormulaR1C1 = "='External Costs B0'!R[14]C[+2]"
    'Range("E26:AK26").FormulaR1C1 = "=Wksht.Cells(40,CostColumns) &"
    'Range("E26:AK26").Formula = "=worksheets('External Costs B0'!)" & ".Cells(40,6)"
    'ActiveCell.Formula = "= worksheets('External Costs B0'!).Cells(40,6).Value"
     ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Next CostColumns
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "='External Costs B0'!" & Cells(73, CostColumns).Address(0, 0)
```

The problem with that is that Rows(73) and Columns(CostColumns) both return a Range object which you can't concatenate to a string.

Comment: Thanks a ton. This worked, and the explanation seems obvious once someone with your wisdom points it out.

Comment: @HobbyHacker, the solution I gave was meant as a quick fix. See other answers to know what good practices are.

Answer (score 0):

Its way easier, if you use `FormulaR1C1` and no selects like in the following sub:
(please change R, RowOffset and FormulaUntilColumn to your needs)

```
Sub Formulas()
Dim I As Integer
Const R As Long = 9     'row
Const RowOffset As Integer = -8
Const ForumulaUntilColumn As Long = 7
    For I = 1 To ForumulaUntilColumn
        Cells(R, I).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[" & RowOffset & "]C[" & I - 1 & "]"
    Next I
End Sub
```

P.S.: add workbook and table name as in any other formula between '=' and 'R['

Comment: Thanks @Jochen This provides a great range of flexibility, appreciate your input

Answer (score 0):

This code will place your formula in cells `Sheet1!A1:AD1`.

The formula in `A1` will be `='External Costs B0'!$A$73`.
In B1 it will be `='External Costs B0'!$C$73` and so on up to `='External Costs B0'!$BG$73` in cell `AD1`.

```
Sub PasteFormula()

    Dim CostColumns As Long
    Dim y As Long

    'Starting column for External Costs reference
    CostColumns = 1

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For y = 1 To 30
            .Cells(1, y).FormulaR1C1 = "='External Costs B0'!R73C" & CostColumns
            CostColumns = CostColumns + 2
        Next y
    End With

End Sub
```

- To update the code change `Sheet1` to whichever sheet you need to
  formula to appear in.
- Change `CostColumn=1` to the correct column
  number you want the formula to refer to.
- Change `y = 1 To 30` to
  the correct columns you want the formula to appear in.

The code uses R1C1 syntax as it's easier to update a formula if you only need to deal with row & column numbers  **R**73**C**2 is row 73, column 2 for example.